# How to decode and save multiple images sent as base64 string array to server directory?

Tags: laravel-5

I am writing a webservice for android app. From the mobile I am sending the image(s) which needs to be decoded and saved as jpg/jpeg/png (any one) format.

The data that will be sent will be a array of base64 which I need to handle it at the backend and save it into a server directory for future references.

To save image my code looks like this. (This is just a test method)

```
public function testing(Request $request){
    $i=0;
    foreach($request['images'] as $name)
    {
        $i +=1;

        $imagename= 'Image'.$i.'.jpeg';
        $destinationPath = public_path('images');
        $path = 'images/'.$imagename;
        $res = file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($name));
    }
}
```

This code will create an image with jpeg extension however when I try to open its just giving me this:
[image]

I think I am missing something.

[Above code is just a demo of uploading a correct file from app.]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother. I fixed it by adding some code.

```
 $i=0;
    foreach($request['images'] as $name)
    {

        list($type, $name) = explode(';', $name);
        list(, $name)      = explode(',', $name);
        $data = base64_decode($name);
        $i +=1;

        $imagename= 'Image'.$i.'.jpeg';
        $destinationPath = public_path('images');
        $path = 'images/'.$imagename;
        $res = file_put_contents($path, $data);

        /*$saveInlistingimages = DB::insert('INSERT INTO listingimages (Listing, Image) values (?, ?)', [$lastId, $path]);*/

    }
```